# Проблемы с Retrofit'ом в API 28 и выше

Tags: android, retrofit

Написал приложение погоды и все это время тестировал на виртуальном устройстве. Там оно работает и выполняет все функции. Но вот после установки на мой телефон Xiaomi у меня просто крутится ProgressBar (который я установил во время загрузки и получения данных). Протестировал на другой телефоне Samsung Galaxy A3 и все заработало так же, как и на виртуальном устройстве. Потом взял другой телефон Xiaomi - та же беда с ProgressBar. Как я понял дело именно в прошивке MiUI. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? И как это исправить?

Comment: Да сталкивался. Никак.

Comment: Мало информации. По идее в логах у вас должна быть ошибка какая-то. Например вы по http на последних версия ОС запрос делаете, что нельзя.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ваш совет помог мне в решении. Оказывается выше API 28 нельзя делать запрос по http. Я отредактирую и правильно поставлю вопрос, чтоб другие могли найти ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в протоколе `http`, а точнее в его использовании. Как мне посоветовал [ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) я изменил тип протокола на `https` и программа заработала корректно на всех версиях Android